# Field Tooltip overlapping with the message of allow blank=false in Extjs

Tags: extjs

Fileds tooltip overlapping with the error message of property allowblank=false in extjs.

```
 xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
        bind: {
            fieldLabel: '{def ? "abc" : "xyz"}',
            tooltip: '{def ?  "tooltip text" : ""}',
        },
        labelWidth: 200,
        columns: 1,
        vertical: true,
        allowBlank: false
```

When any checkbox is not selected it shows an error tip to check atleast one checkbox due to allowBlank:false property and this message overlaps my tooltip.
Any suggestions for its fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can position your error message. The location where the error message text should display.

The following are values that have predefined meaning:

**CLASSIC**

**msgTarget** : String

The location where the error message text should display. Must be one of the following values:

- **qtip** Display a quick tip containing the message when the user hovers over the field. This is the default.
  Ext.tip.QuickTipManager#init must have been called for this setting to work.
- **title** Display the message in a default browser title attribute popup.
- **under** Add a block div beneath the field containing the error message.
- **side** Add an error icon to the right of the field, displaying the message in a - popup on hover.
- **none** Don't display any error message. This might be useful if you are implementing custom error display.
  **[element id]** Add the error message directly to the innerHTML of the specified element.

Defaults to: 'qtip'

**MODERN**

**errorTarget**

- **qtip** Display a Ext.tip.Manager containing the message when the user hovers (or taps) the field. For this option to work, quick tips must be enabled by calling Ext.tip.Manager#init.
- **side** Add an error icon to the right of the field, displaying the message in a popup on hover or tap.
- **title** Display the message in a default browser title attribute.
- **under** Add a div beneath the field containing the error message.
  Defaults to:

'qtip'

Doku Link:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.field.Field.html#cfg-errorTarget